# Как присвоить ститичный ip адрес компьютеру в wifi?

Tags: ip, роутер

Имеется роутер Интеркросс, куплен статичный ip адрес, как присвоить его к определенному компьютеру?Помогите пожалуйста. Я действительно сижу с этой проблемой весь день.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По пробросу портов можно написать целое руководство, но я не думаю что hashcode создан для этого, вкратце напишу, что проброс портов создан для того что-бы открывать порты лишь для определённых устройств в сети управляемой роутером.

Т.о. есть у тебя сервер CS 1.6, открываешь на входящие порт 15000 (по моему) и направляешь на комп с запущенным сервером CS 1.6, теперь к тебе из интернета могут коннектиться вбивая в качестве адреса сервера твой внешний IP (твой статичный адрес)

А вот как это делать - ищи в гугле, в разных роутерах по разному. Именно Интеркросс я не знаю, пользуюсь лишь DLink Dir 320

Comment: @cvdemol Спасибо что объяснили, подскажите пожалуйста что конкретно нужно вписать в эти поля (на изображении)? С моим интерфейсом в гугле ничего подобного не делали.http://s002.radikal.ru/i199/1406/29/5477cf854711.png

Comment: (ответил тут)[http://admin.hashcode.ru/questions/10205/ip-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85-%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81-icxeth-5670-ne?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=10207#10207]

Answer (score 1):

> Имеется роутер Интеркросс, куплен статичный ip адрес, как присвоить его к определенному компьютеру?

Только роутеру, на WAN порт, а дальше проброс нужных портов на нужный комьтер.

Comment: Можно по подробнее? Я впервые имею дело с этим

Comment: Ключевые слова для гуглинга "port forwarding" или "проброс портов". Настройки (расположение и название кнопочек) различается у роутеров разных производителей (иногда и в разных моделях). Для начала нужно пробиться в админку роутера, а что делать дальше нужно смотреть в инструкции к нему.

Comment: Уже в админке, в инструкции ничего по этому поводу полезного не нашел. Найденное по "проброс портов" ничем мне не помогло, еще больше запутался что к чему и откуда.